# react-apexcharts / chart not visible

Tags: reactjs, apexcharts

I'm trying to render a basic bar charts with react-apexcharts but I can't display it for some reason.

I started with the example given in the documentation aka

```
const CustomChart: React.FC = () => {
    const [data, setData] = useState({
    options: {
        chart: {
            id: 'apexchart-example'
        },
        xaxis: {
            categories: [1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999]
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'series-1',
        data: [30, 40, 35, 50, 49, 60, 70, 91, 125]
    }]
});

return (
    <Chart
        options={data.options}
        series={data.series}
        type='bar'
        width={500}
    />
);
```

It renders something as I can check in the inspector that there is data & I can actually download the chart with the options given by react-apexcharts (we can see the menu with these options on the image I shared).

[chart is invisible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YWtzs.png)

As for the rendering, nothing fancy I just import and render in my page the CustomChart component I've created...

I checked the documentation similar issues but didnt find anything. I'm working with :

- "react-apexcharts": "^1.4.0",
- "react": "^17.0.2",
- "apexcharts": "^3.35.3",

Thanks for the help